# Angle between roots in a root system

Tags: finite-groups, reflection, root-systems, coxeter-groups

Let $\Phi$ be a root system in the following sense: (1) $\Phi \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ consists of a finite number of nonzero vectors, (2) for each $\alpha \in \Phi$, $\Phi \cap \mathbb{R} \alpha = \{-\alpha,\alpha\}$ and (3) for each $\alpha \in \Phi$, $s_\alpha \Phi = \Phi$ where $s_\alpha$ is the reflection in $\alpha$.

Questions:

1. What can we say about the angles between the roots? By looking at the pictures of root systems, it seems that two adjacent roots have an angle of $2\pi/n$ between them... how can this be stated and shown rigorously?
2. If nothing can be said for question 1 (which I doubt), then can one say something about the angles between simple roots?

This isn't really in the context of Lie algebras, so much as reflection and coxeter groups (I'm studying Humpfrey's *Reflection Groups and Coxeter Groups*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wlog. $\Phi$ spans $\mathbb R^n$.
If the angle between two roots $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ is $\beta$, then $s_{\alpha_1}\circ s_{\alpha_2}$ is a rotation by $2\beta$. Viewed as a permutation of $\Phi$, this rotation has some finite order $k$. As $\Phi$ spand the whole space, the rotation itself also has order $k$, i.e. $2k\beta$ is a multiple of $2\pi$.

For simple roots, we can say even more: The angle between these is one of $\frac12\pi$, $\frac23\pi$, $\frac34\pi$, $\frac56\pi$ (in other words: it is $\pi-\frac1k\pi$ with $k\in\{1,2,3,4,6\}$). One shows this by checking which values the scalar product can assume.

Comment: I think your comment about simple roots is only true for crystallographic Coxeter groups, i.e. all Coxeter groups with the following exceptions: $H_4$, $H_3$ and the dihedral groups.